# Xamarin.Forms load pin async in Android proj

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm loading my pins `async` and it works well if I don't use a custom map. But if I use a custom map in my`Android project` it doesn't work anymore. My `custom Pin list` is null. I can understand it's because I'm loading the pins async and that the custom Pin list hasn't been initialized. But how do I solve it? Is it much work to fix this in all platforms (Android, iOS, UWP)?

```
    public CustomMap Map { get; set; }

    public async Task InitilizePins()
    {
        var pins = (await new SamplePins().GetPinsAsync()).ToList();
        Map.CustomPins = pins;

        foreach (var customPin in pins)
        {
            Map.Pins.Add(customPin.Pin);
        }
    }

    public class CustomMap : Map
    {
        public List<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my custom map in Android. My custom pins are null on my forms map variable.

```
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;

            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To tell for sure we need full sample project to track this. But most likely your renderer is called before you set your pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can understand it's because I'm loading the pins async and that the custom Pin list hasn't been initialized. But how do I solve it?

The fastest way to fix the problem is to change `CustomPins` from `List<CustomPin>` to `ObservableCollection<CustomPin>`(you will need to change all the related codes in your projects).

Then register the `ObservableCollection<CustomPin>`'s `CollectionChanged` event in your Android project:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged (e);

    if (e.OldElement != null) {
        NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;

    }

    if (e.NewElement != null) {
        var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
        //register the CollectionChanged event
        formsMap.CustomPins.CollectionChanged += CustomPins_CollectionChanged;
        customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
        Control.GetMapAsync(this);
    }
}

private void CustomPins_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    customPins = (ObservableCollection<CustomPin>)sender;
    //rerender all the pins in the map
    NativeMap.Clear();

    foreach (var pin in customPins)
    {
        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));

        NativeMap.AddMarker(marker);
    }
    isDrawn = true;
}
```

Then whenever you add new pins, `CustomPins_CollectionChanged` will be triggered and map's pins will be rerendered.

Comment: It actually worked to change my custom pin list to ObservableCollection. Instead of have my customPins as a private field I made my formsMap to it. If I need to get my custom pins, I'll get it from my formsMap field.

Comment: By the way if I need to do something when they are added, then the CollectionChanged fix that. (I only needed to get the custom pin from my collection that I clicked on).